# I am getting a SIGABRT error when playing background music under viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is my code

.h file

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;

}


.m file

  -(void)viewDidLoad {

  [self backgroundMusic];

  }

   -(void)backgroundMusic {

    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setActive:YES error:nil];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FirstQuestionGameSoundtrack" ofType:@"m4a"];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];

    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    [theAudio prepareToPlay];
    [theAudio setVolume:1];
    theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;

    [theAudio play];


}
```

That is my code and I am getting a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error.

If there is a better way of playing background music on an app under a viewController, I would love to know how to do that. Thank you!

This is the error

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); //Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error.    
}
}
```

console log

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
0x3a364df4:  mov    r12, #0x148
0x3a364df8:  svc    #0x80
0x3a364dfc:  blo    0x3a364e14                ; __pthread_kill + 32  //Thread 1: SIGABRT
0x3a364e00:  ldr    r12, [pc, #4]             ; __pthread_kill + 24
0x3a364e04:  ldr    r12, [pc, r12]
0x3a364e08:  b      0x3a364e10                ; __pthread_kill + 28
0x3a364e0c:  rsbeq  r5, lr, #0x80000001
0x3a364e10:  bx     r12
0x3a364e14:  bx     lr



*** ImageIO - could not find ColorSync function 'ColorSyncProfileCreateSanitizedCopy'
2014-12-11 23:59:39.500 The Wild Game[3413:563583] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2c275c1f 0x39d1ec8b 0x2c275b65 0x2cf0ae6d 0xfd9eb 0xfd7af 0x2f734f8f 0x2f734cfd 0x2f73abcb 0x2f73863d 0x2f7a283d 0x2f99468b 0x2f996afb 0x2f9a1379 0x2f995387 0x329d90e9 0x2c23c39d 0x2c23b661 0x2c239de3 0x2c188211 0x2c188023 0x2f7993ef 0x2f7941d1 0xfe61d 0x3a29eaaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. Can you post the console log for stacks of events?

Comment: I added it to my question. Hope you can see it @RichaSharma

Comment: Okay I changed it @RichaSharma

Comment: @RichaSharma not yet I haven't tried it yet but I will later today. Thank you though I appreciate it! I'll let you know if it works

Comment: Can you check Spelling, Location, Type, Permissions, etc... The mian problem here is your app is not getting the path to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stack trace for Crash says you are passing `nil` as a parameter in `-[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]` method. That's why it's crashing.

Right after

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FirstQuestionGameSoundtrack" ofType:@"m4a"];`
```

Try printing it as

```
NSLog(@"%@", path);
```

You are getting it `nil`

Make sure that you add that file to your project, and it appears in a `Copy Bundle Resources` build phase in your executable's target in Xcode.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I was about to point out what you just edited moments ago. :)

Comment: @RichaSharma Hey so what do I change exactly? And does the length of the music file matter?

Comment: @CyrilIvarGarcia Does it return `nil`. If YES, then you have to make sure that the file DO exist in Bundle Resources.

Comment: @CyrilIvarGarcia Let us continue the discussion [Here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66806/sigabrt)

Comment: @RichaSharma sure let me get on my computer